# Getting what you are trying to avoid, by trying to avoid it

Tags: reference-request, terminology

Sometimes you want to avoid something, but by attempting to avoid that, precisely that which you tried to avoid happens.

A typical example could be: a girl is pregnant, but don't want to draw attention to herself, so she doesn't tell anyone about the pregnancy and isolates herself. But by doing this, she now draws even more attention to herself, and in the process even upsets many people, because of just that. If she just went on normally, and told people as she cross them, she might just have not drew that much attention because most people are too busy living their own lives.

Another example: a person might be extremely health conscious, and in his/her everlasting search to eat even more healthy, they "discover", what they deem, the next super-food. Now they eat this new food in abundance, overdoing it, and as a result start developing health issues. If they just stuck with what is deemed healthy by most health conscious people, they would have been okay.

My question is twofold:
1. Is there a recognized name for this, and
2. Are there any classical literary works that could be used to illustrate this poetically.

Comment: This is called [Streisand effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streisand_effect), "*named after American entertainer Barbra Streisand, whose attempt to suppress photographs of her residence in Malibu, California inadvertently drew further attention to it in 2003*".

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/).